# Customize website UI as a user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create an alternative UI for an awful website that I need to use everyday, and my eyes are bleeding. So, I first try to create an HTML document and embed the site via an iframe and just use jQuery an CSS to modify the UI.

```
<iframe src="site-to-modify">
```

But you cannot access the site DOM for security reasons. 
Any way to do this without using plugins like Stylish (https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/stylish/) Just using HTML+CSS+js, and frameworks based on those. Is this possible? :D

Comment: look into the browser extensions Stylish and Greasemonkey.

Answer (score 1):

when you try to embed side from other domain in your webpage this will cause error due to [same origin policy](http://qnimate.com/same-origin-policy-in-nutshell/). For your case rather than trying to manipulate the dom directly if the site offers some REST api you can use it to build your own front end for it. technically building your own UI by manipulation of dom for the site is possible just not easy.
The other way to do this is to develop small extension for chrome or firefox that uses either chrome developer console API or that of Firefox and apply these style changes by default when the site is opened.

Comment: There is no REST api, that would be great. I don't want to make big changes, just styling and delete some content leaving the important things.
Thanks for your response.

Comment: In that case, why not a browser plugin? [Reddit Enhancement Suite](http://redditenhancementsuite.com/) does something similar to what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

As user93 said, you're going to face CORS issues. If you don't want to use Stylish or want more fine-grained control, the best option (assuming there's no API you can use) is to write a server that scrapes this website for information and serves it up as JSON, or as regular HTML.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. I didn't have that in mind, but I will consider the possibility. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the type of content that the website is serving, and the information that you want to view, http://www.socket.io could be used to implement this idea assuming that the alternative UI is either going to be hosted somewhere, or you have a Node server running locally.